# как реализовать правильную анимацию загрузки и clearInterval после загрузки каждой картинки

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
let imageInterval;

imageInterval = setInterval(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (images[i].complete) {
      images[i].classList.remove('spinner');
    } else {
      images[i].classList.add('spinner');
    }
  }
}, 50);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

img {
  width: 100vh;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto;
  animation: loading-bar-spinner 0.50s linear infinite;
}

.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 4px transparent;
  border-top-color: #000000;
  border-left-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: hidden;
}

@keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612637829340-c91db24ca338?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612694537513-b772cb21f725?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612712393889-c8ffe831ba9f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612697433795-e2b675b15bfd?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612640189088-9b0fda86cad7?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
```

Как реализовать clearinterval тут только после того как все элементы будут загружены? можно сделать проверку отдельно для каждого индекса - (if images[n0].complete && images [n1].complete images[n2].complete и т.п.), но так будет не  красиво, да и вдруг у меня будет массив из 200 картинок? + как сделать чтобы при воспроизведении анимации не было части загруженной картинки? Чтобы не было вот так : (как видите тут часть не загруженной картинки, а мне такое не надо) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как реализовать clearinterval тут только после того как все элементы будут загружены?

Изначально не запускать его =) Т.к. он служит костыльным методом, чтобы поймать завершение загрузки. Для этого существует событие `load`.

> Как сделать чтобы при воспроизведении анимации не было части загруженной картинки?

В setInterval замените 50 на 1000: проблема станет еще очевиднее. Часть загруженной картинки проскакивает из-за временного зазора между загрузкой картинки и следующим тиком интервала через 50мс.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  // Если картинка и так успела загрузиться, ничего не надо делать.
  if (!images[i].complete) {
    images[i].classList.add('spinner');        
    images[i].addEventListener("load", remove_loader);
  }
}

function remove_loader() {
  this.classList.remove('spinner');      
};
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto;
  animation: loading-bar-spinner 0.50s linear infinite;
}

.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 4px transparent;
  border-top-color: #000000;
  border-left-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: hidden;
}

@keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612637829340-c91db24ca338?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612694537513-b772cb21f725?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612712393889-c8ffe831ba9f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612697433795-e2b675b15bfd?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612640189088-9b0fda86cad7?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
```

---

Проблема предыдущего ответа: событие load уменьшает временной зазор, но картинка всё равно мелькает до удаления loader-а. `requestAnimationFrame` тоже не помогает, пропускает один кадр.

«В лоб» железобетонно можно решить, если завернуть картинку во временный блок, который сам будет loader-ом, и будет через CSS скрывать внутренний img до его загрузки:

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  if (!images[i].complete) wrap_tmp_loader(images[i]);
}

function wrap_tmp_loader(img) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "spinner";
  
  img.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", div);
  // Вставка div перед текущим img

  div.appendChild(img);
  // appendChild не копирует элемент, а переносит (во внутрь div)
  
  img.addEventListener("load", destroy_tmp_loader);
};

function destroy_tmp_loader() {
  let img = this;
  let div = this.parentNode;
  
  div.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", img);
  // Возвращает картинку туда, где она изначально была

  div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
  // Удаляет блок, будто ничего не было
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.spinner {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 100px auto;
  animation: loading-bar-spinner 0.50s linear infinite;
  
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  
  border: solid 4px transparent;
  border-top-color: #000000;
  border-left-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.spinner > img {
  /* Картинка гаратированно будет скрыта, пока находится внутри блока */
  display: none;
}

@keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612637829340-c91db24ca338?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612694537513-b772cb21f725?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612712393889-c8ffe831ba9f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612697433795-e2b675b15bfd?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612640189088-9b0fda86cad7?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
```

Comment: Гениально(без шуток), спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Thrackerzod * Отредактировано.

Answer (score 1):

Спиннер немного не тот, т.к. не получилось добиться чистого полукруга. А в остальном всё работает.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    let img = images[i];
    img.classList.add("loading");
    let controlImage = new Image();
    controlImage.src = img.getAttribute("source");
    controlImage.onload = function() {
        img.src = controlImage.src;
        img.removeAttribute("source");
        img.classList.remove("loading");
    };
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
img {
    width: 100vh;
}

.loading {
    animation: loading-bar-spinner 0.5s linear infinite;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-top: #000 solid 4px;
    border-left: #000 solid 4px;
    border-right: transparent solid 0px;
    border-bottom: transparent solid 0px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

@keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <img source="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612637829340-c91db24ca338?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
   <img source="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612694537513-b772cb21f725?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
   <img source="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612712393889-c8ffe831ba9f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
   <img source="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612697433795-e2b675b15bfd?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
   <img source="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612640189088-9b0fda86cad7?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам задал, сам ответил, лол.

js

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
let imageInterval;

imageInterval = setInterval(() => {
   for(let i = 0;i < images.length;i++){
      if(clearIntervalFunction){
         clearInterval(imageInterval);
            if(images[i].complete){
               images[i].classList.remove('spinner');
      }else{
         images[i].classList.add('spinner');
      }
   }
}
}, 50);

function clearIntervalFunction(elem){
   return elem.complete;
}
```

css

```
.spinner{width: 0px;
height: 0px;border:  solid 4px transparent;
border-top-color:  #000000;
border-left-color: #000000;border-radius: 100%;
background: hidden;
padding: 20px;}
```